# Posting data from HTML form to the PHP action Script

Tags: php, html, forms, payment-gateway

I can get the .php file to work with the sample data in it.  However, I have tried several ways to get an html form to post the variables into the php.  What is the best way to do this?  I am attaching the .php with the sample data in it that works on the site.  When I try to use an .html file and post to this it stops at the BluPay.php file and nothing happens and the transaction fails to send the data.  This is only test data so nothing is real inside for credit card information.

```
<?php
/**
* BluePay PHP Sample Code
*
* This code sample runs a $3.00 Credit Card Sale transaction
* against a customer using test payment information.
* If using TEST mode, odd dollar amounts will return
* an approval and even dollar amounts will return a decline.
*
*/

include('BluePay.php');

$accountID = "XXXXXXXX";
$secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$mode = "TEST";

$payment = new BluePay(
    $accountID,
    $secretKey,
    $mode
);

$payment->setCustomerInformation(array(
    'firstName' => 'Bob', 
    'lastName' => 'Tester', 
    'addr1' => '1234 Test St.', 
    'addr2' => 'Apt #500', 
    'city' => 'Testville', 
    'state' => 'IL', 
    'zip' =>'54321', 
    'country' => 'USA', 
    'phone' => '1231231234', 
    'email' => 'test@bluepay.com' 
));

$payment->setCCInformation(array(
    'cardNumber' => '4111111111111111', // Card Number: 4111111111111111
    'cardExpire' => '1217', // Card Expire: 12/15
    'cvv2' => '123' // Card CVV2: 123
));

$payment->sale('3.00'); // Sale Amount: $3.00

 // Makes the API request with BluePAy
$payment->process();

// Reads the response from BluePay
if($payment->isSuccessfulResponse()){
    echo 
    'Transaction Status: '. $payment->getStatus() . "\n" .
    'Transaction Message: '. $payment->getMessage() . "\n" .
    'Transaction ID: '. $payment->getTransID() . "\n" .
    'AVS Response: ' . $payment->getAVSResponse() . "\n" .
    'CVS Response: ' . $payment->getCVV2Response() . "\n" .
    'Masked Account: ' . $payment->getMaskedAccount() . "\n" .
    'Card Type: ' . $payment->getCardType() . "\n" .
    'Authorization Code: ' . $payment->getAuthCode() . "\n";
} else{
    echo $payment->getMessage() . "\n";
}
?>
```

Here is one of the html I was using to post to the php above after I removed the values:

```
<form action="ccpost.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="accountID" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="secretKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="TEST" />
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
Address 1: <input type="text" name="addr1"><br>
Address 2: <input type="text" name="addr2"><br>
City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
State: <input type="text" name="state"><br>
Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
Country: <input type="text" name="country"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Card Number: <input type="text" name="cardNumber"><br>
Card Expire: <input type="text" name="cardExpire"><br>
Cvv: <input type="text" name="cvv2"><br>
Sale: <input type="text" name="sale"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is the current php I am trying to post to.  So I took the variables and use the $_POST.  However I am getting an PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' around the accountID line.

```
<?php

include('BluePay.php');

$payment = new BluePay(
    $accountID = $_POST["accountID"];
    $secretKey = $_POST["secretKey"];
    $mode = $_POST["mode"];
);

$payment->setCustomerInformation(array(
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$addr1 = $_POST["addr1"]; 
$addr2 = $_POST["addr2"];
$city = $_POST["city"]; 
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"]; 
$email = $_POST["email"];
));

$payment->setCCInformation(array(
    'cardNumber' => '4111111111111111', // Card Number: 4111111111111111
    'cardExpire' => '1217', // Card Expire: 12/15
    'cvv2' => '123' // Card CVV2: 123
));

$payment->sale('3.00'); // Sale Amount: $3.00

 // Makes the API request with BluePay
$payment->process();

// Reads the response from BluePay
if($payment->isSuccessfulResponse()){
    echo 
    'Transaction Status: '. $payment->getStatus() . "\n" .
    'Transaction Message: '. $payment->getMessage() . "\n" .
    'Transaction ID: '. $payment->getTransID() . "\n" .
    'AVS Response: ' . $payment->getAVSResponse() . "\n" .
    'CVS Response: ' . $payment->getCVV2Response() . "\n" .
    'Masked Account: ' . $payment->getMaskedAccount() . "\n" .
    'Card Type: ' . $payment->getCardType() . "\n" .
    'Authorization Code: ' . $payment->getAuthCode() . "\n";
} else{
    echo $payment->getMessage() . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: share your html code plz

Comment: Post the markup from your form.

Comment: are you sure you are using the right file name in form action??? ccpost.php???

Comment: you're not accessing any of the `$_POST` data in your PHP file

Comment: if the file is correct, probably you should check at the start of php file if you are receiving the data in $_POST array by print_r($_POST);

Comment: Yes, that is what I named a modified version of the first file where I removed the test values with the goal it would get them on the post.  Instead it stops on the include.

Comment: what do you get against print_r($_POST) in your php file at start of the page???

Comment: Array ( [accountID] => XXXXXXXXX  [secretKey] => XXXXXXXXXXXX [mode] => TEST [firstName] => Bob [lastName] => Tester [addr1] => 123 main [addr2] => Apt 500 [city] => Testville [state] => IL [zip] => 54321 [country] => USA [phone] => 1231231234 [email] => test@bluepay.com [cardNumber] => 4111111111111111 [cardExpire] => 1217 [cvv2] => 123 [sale] => 3.00 )

Comment: I removed everything in the php file except for the print_r($_POST) and it does show the elements fine.

Comment: Then I used this to set the variables in the php file $accountID = ($_POST['accountID'];
$secretKey = ($_POST['secretKey'];

Answer (score 1):

since I can't see your .html file, it's not so easy to provide you a specific answer. But the best I can do is to recommend you this tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
There you should find everything.

Basicly you have to put your .php script to an 'action tag' of your .html, use method GET or POST and then in .php take the data from globals $_GET or $_POST.

Comment: So can I take the variables and call them like this $firstName = ($_POST['firstName'];

Comment: Yes, like this:
`$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];`
Your input in html form should have a tag name="firstName" (you already have it like this, i wrote it just to make it clear).

Comment: I am getting an error unexpected ;  $payment = new BluePay(
    $accountID = $_POST["accountID"];
    $secretKey = $_POST["secretKey"];
    $mode = $_POST["mode"];
);